# Filter array with JSONPath depending on subarray information

Tags: javascript, json, xpath, jsonpath

I have JSON with an array of movies like in https://www.w3resource.com/JSON/JSONPath-with-JavaScript.php but with additional array of actors and with implicit type information (database, movies).

I created this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prorep/7nhvb6sg/15/

I try to filter this array for all movies where a specific actor participates.
When i try something like this:

```
jsonPath(json, "$.[actors[?(@.id==2)]]")
```

I only get an array with the actor twice but not the full movie. So i think the problem is maybe with defining the root element - but what also does not work is
`$.*[...], $.[*][...], $[*.[...]], ...`

What i try to get as result:

```
    [{
     "name": "30 Minutes or Less",
     "genre": "adventure",
     "director": "Ruben Fleischer",
     "Facebook_like": 114,
     "actors": [{
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Jesse Eisenberg"
     }]
   },
   {
     "name": "The Social Network",
     "genre": "Biography",
     "director": "David Fincher",
     "Facebook_like": 0,
     "actors": [{
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Jesse Eisenberg"
     }]
   }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question. You are using Goessner's reference JSONPath implementation (the guy who came up with [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)) in your sample as well as the live test on the tutorial page (the download link on the page seems to link to a slightly different version). The query you came up with is actually not supported and it only works partially. The evaluated path is the same as a recursive descent matching all `id`s with the value 2: `$..[?(@.id==2)]`, the actors part is ignored. You can call this a bug, unsupported syntax, or incomplete implementation. The problem is, JSONPath is not (yet) standardized and different implementations have different features, and more or less subtle path definitions.

While this does not work in the reference (JS) implementation, we can still find other implementations that can query the data as requested.

I the JavaScript world, we could use [JsonPath-Plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath) (which is probably one of the feature-richest implementations as of today) using extended syntax to grab the parent `$..[?(@.id ==2)]^` using `^` at the end and a parser flag to get that parent of the parent, ie. the property that has the actors array

```
JSONPath({json: json,
          path: "$..[?(@.id ==2)]^",
          wrap: false,
          resultType: 'parent'});
```

as demonstrated below:

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script type="module">

import {JSONPath} from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonpath-plus@4.0.0/dist/index-es.js';

 const json = [{
     "name": "The Change-Up",
     "genre": "comedy",
     "director": "David Dobkin",
     "Facebook_like": 252,
     "actors": [{
       "id": 1,
       "name": "Ryan Reynolds"
     }]
   },
   {
     "name": "Rise of the Planet of the Apes",
     "genre": "SciFi",
     "director": "Rupert Wyatt",
     "Facebook_like": 472,
     "actors": []
   },
   {
     "name": "30 Minutes or Less",
     "genre": "adventure",
     "director": "Ruben Fleischer",
     "Facebook_like": 114,
     "actors": [{
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Jesse Eisenberg"
     }]
   },
   {
     "name": "Final Destination 5",
     "genre": "Horror",
     "director": "Steven Quale",
     "Facebook_like": 241,
     "actors": []
   },
   {
     "name": "The Social Network",
     "genre": "Biography",
     "director": "David Fincher",
     "Facebook_like": 0,
     "actors": [{
       "id": 2,
       "name": "Jesse Eisenberg"
     }]
   }
 ];

 console.log(JSONPath({
        json: json,
        path: "$..[?(@.id ==2)]^",
        wrap: false,
        resultType: 'parent'
}));

</script>
```

Another very robust JSONPath implementation that can query the requested elements is [Jayway's implementation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) for Java. Again, the following semantically sound path (for me) does not work with many other implementations:

```
$.[?(@.actors[*].id ==[2])]
```

You can try the query yourself online [here](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) and further explore differences among other implementations.

The reality is, you need to refer to the documentation of your specific implementation to make good use of JSONPath in your project.

Comment: You are right with the point that I was not aware that there are differences between the multiple available implementations. Thank you for giving the alternative examples.